# Comparing values within an array

Tags: java, sudoku

So, I asked a question 2 days ago, I'm going to try to rework it to make it simpler:

I have a 2D array, which represents a Sudoku game.

I'm trying to check the game for errors as with a typical Sudoku game:

No number (1-9) is repeated within a row, column or 3x3 square. No empty cells.

The user IS ALLOWED to enter a repeat value, but the game will not be considered "won" until they fix these errors.  I want to allow them to enter wrong values, just not win.

I'm very new to Java, so I had a limited knowledge to approach this with. I was going to try a long if, else statement comparing all the cells. That didn't work, because -1 was repeated. (-1 represents an empty square). I tried to get around this, but realized that this if statement was too messy and there had to be a better way.

Then I thought to use boolean statements to test each number, setting to true if it had been seen before.  That seems messy with so many boolean statements.

So, I'm kind of at a wall.  Any tips on what to try? Try not to use anything advance, only been doing Java 2 months.

Comment: You can start by writing small methods like `private boolean checkRow(int rowIndex)`, 'private boolean checkCol(int colIndex)` which will check for the validity of just only the specified row or column, and return true or false. Test the methods. And then move forword for the 3x3 sqares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You want to loop through the values, such as with a for loop. That will be *much* better than a long if-else-if chain.

2) To keep track of values seen, a simple way for you would probably be to use a list. I'll try to keep this example as simple as possible since you ask for "nothing advance."

```
public boolean checkRow(int rowNumber)
{
    ArrayList numbersSeen = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i += 1)
    {
        if(sudokuArray[i][rowNumber] != -1 && numbersSeen.contains(sudokuArray[i][rowNumber]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will return true if row `rowNumber` has a number repeat in the 2D array specified by `sudokuArray`, and false otherwise. Notice the `sudokuArray != -1`, that takes into account the -1 placeholder for empty squares that you mentioned.

When you compile something like this, if the compiler errors about trying to put an integer into the array list, you might have to make it generic by specifying `ArrayList<Integer>`. I do not recall if Java will auto-box a primitive for you when you specify a destination of type Object.

This then leads into a small side-lesson which might be beneficial to you since you are new: Java has both primitive types (boolean, byte, short, int, long, float, double) and object versions of the primitive types (Boolean, Byte, Integer, etc.). If you do `int i = 0;` and `Integer i2 = i;`, Java will be nice enough to do the conversion for you.

`checkColumn` would be very similar. `check3X3area` (or whatever you would want to call it) could be somewhat similar; perhaps you could use 2 for-loops, one nested inside the other, and loop 3 times each instead of 9. This will be left as an exercise for you.

Also, you could make this generic to allow for sudoku boards that are not of size 9 with a few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

For each group (row, column or 3x3 square): set sum = 0, and for each value n not -1 encountered, set sum = sum | 2^n.  When you are done, if sum is not 2^10 - 2, then the group has a duplicate.  (Obviously, if you encounter a -1, you don't have a winner).  (If you look at the values in binary, you'll see what's going on.)

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

```
     int [][] numbers = new int[3][3];
     int[] rowSum = new int[]{0,0,0};
     int[] colSum =new int[]{0,0,0};

    //validate duplicate 
    for(int i=0; i< 2; i++){
       boolean duplicate = false;
       for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
          if(numbers[i][j]==numbers[i+1][j] || 
             numbers[i][j]==numbers[i][j+1]){
             System.out.println("duplicate");
             duplicate = true;
             break;
       }
       if(duplicate){
           break;
       }
     }

     //sum rows and columns
     for(int i=0; i< 3; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
          rowSum[i] = rowSum[i] + numbers[i][j];
          colSum[j] = colSum[j] + numbers[i][j];
       }
     }

     //validate row and column sums
     for(int i=0; i< 3; i++){
       if((rowSum[i] != 15) || (colSum[i]!=15)){
         System.out.println("incorrect sum");
         break;
       }
     }
```

Comment: Your "validate duplicate" section looks like it will only check a single number next to it on the i axis and a single number next to it on the j axis. I do not think that is correct, please clarify if I am missing some point there. The other two parts taken together though, the "sum rows and columns" and "validate row and column sums" I like, and assuming the board is entirely filled in I think it should even find duplicates as well, without actually checking for duplicates - clever. Your entire solution only works for boards of size 3, but that can be easily changed.

Comment: That's correct. But if two numbers are not duplicate and sum is 15, I think its OK condition, otherwise either rowsum or colsum will be different.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `homework` but I will try to provide some suggestions.

Consider a `class Sudoku` which is the entire board. This board is made up `81` `cells`. The first constraint is that any cell can contain a number between `1` and `9` and a special value `0` to signal that it has not been filled in. the constraint is easy to verify.

Now, there are different *projections* of this board:

- There are `9` `rows` and `9` `column`. The constraint is on these rows and columns is that nu number can be repeated and none of them can be `0`. How to do you verify this consraint is satisfied? One way is to create a an array of `9` `booleans`, each signifying whether the number at that index is *seen*. Start with all false, iterate a row or column, setting the value at index to true for each number in the cell. At the end, if this latter array contains only `true` then constaint is met.
- Another projection is the nine suares. Again, the same constaint applies.

These rows, columns and square need to knwo where their cells are on the board. You should be able to implement that. For example, row 7 would consist of `cell[6,0]` through `cell[6,8]`.

After every move, check the constraints, if they are satisfied for all cells, rows, columns and squares then the game is complete.